# Scroll Up Reveal Animation with Framer Motion

Tags: animation, framer-motion

Does anyone know how to do scroll-up reveal animation like this one  https://www.mi.com/global/redmi-note-9-pro with framer motion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can track motion values of each element using useElementScrollHook and then You can map it useTransform Hook creating new motion values for animation and then use it in an animate tag or style tag of main page Element along with motion component...you can build even better with framer motion...

Comment: How it could be done using framer-motion?